# Generate numbers as part of a brute force application

Tags: java, arrays, integer, helper

Firstly please note that I am knew to Java. I have undertook a brute force application that I know has two numbers in the password to crack.

When I generate a string such as ABC, I need to put two numbers in all possible positions of this string (which I have done!)

I need two numbers that are generated from 0 - 9 each. This includes a possibility from 00 to 99 when both numbers are put together.

I have thought about this quite a lot and believe it may be a better idea to have one integer number that increments and then I can split into two integers to feed back to my main, however I cannot actually start a integer from 00, 01, 02, 03.. where the first poistion would be fNum and second sNum. It will be 1, 2, 3, 4 until 10.

So far I have come up with the following solution but it doesnt quite work as I want it too..

```
public int twoNumber(int fNum, int sNum){

    //form array from two integers
    int[] intArray = {fNum, sNum};

    //increment the array value (not sure if correct way?)
    intArray++;        

    //split the array to get two indiivudla numbers
    int[] part1 = new int[99];
    int[] part2 = new int[99];

    System.arraycopy(intArray, 0, part1, 0, part1.length);
    System.arraycopy(intArray, part1.length, part2, 0, part2.length);

    //I need to convert the two above and return the two numbers as integers
    //and not arrays

}
```

I am not 100% sure this is the best possible way to go about doing this but the programme should return something as the following:

Say we start with A in the brtue force.

```
0A0
0A1
0A3
..
0A9
1A0
..
9A9
..
0AB0
0AB1
0AB2
0AB3
```

And so on.

My question is, is the best way to go about this problem as forming an array, incrementing, splitting and returning? I have also thought about other ways such as creating an array of all the possible numbers (takes too long), using random in java, creating a single integer, incremneting, splitting and returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like "homework" or "project", so the advice here will be about the algorithm you will use and some of the ways to put things together, rather than a working program to do that.

First, the algorithm.  It looks like you need generate a trial password from a base string with two integers in all of the possible combinations of places.  So you need an algorithm that cycles through all possible combinations of "added integer" locations in the string ... and for each of those combinations, run through the 100 combinatins of the integer values.

In pseudo code, assuming you have location `loca` and `locb` you might do something like:

```
for num1=0 to 9
     for num2=0 to 9
      form candidate password by inserting num1 in loca and num2 in locb
     end for
   end for
```

you may want to simplify by making three strings front (chars up to `loca -1`), middle (chars from `loca` to `locb`), and back (chars from `locb` to end) and replace with

candidate = front + num1 + middle + num2 + back

Comment: I have left, as an exercise, how you handle all the location pairs

Comment: Hi, this is not homework or a project... I want to see the difference between brute forcing using a generator which has numbers and letters versus a generator of text then adding two numbers in all possible positions... I have already done this, I now need a way of generating two numbers, that is all. Very simple yet I am struggling have spent my day trying to do this.

Comment: You are stuck on generating the two numbers?!  use a for loop like the pseudocde

Comment: I know its a simple task. It is quite difficult though because the numbers need to be considered as one overall number which has the possibilities of 00 to 99. I need a way of generating this number then splitting it however as I found out the numbers cant start from 01 it will be 1... And thus my final idea of an array, putting the two numbers in, incrementing the array in value, then splitting and returning the value. But I have no idea if this is the best way and cant even get this to work as the return values will need to be integers and not int[].

Comment: Look at the pseudo-code .. you don't need to generate a two-digit number, use the digits separately